# VBA if statement mismach error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple if statement. This if statement should move to the else statement when the value does not satisfy else if, but instead excel gives me a error 13 mismach error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CALULATE()
Dim postage As String
Dim discountplaceholder As String

discount = Range("d10").Value

If discount = 0.1 Then

MsgBox "hello Bill"
discountplaceholder = 0.1

ElseIf discount = 0.05 Then

MsgBox "hello BOB"
discountplaceholder = 0.05

Else
MsgBox "hello dan"
discountplaceholder = 0

End If
End Sub
```

The third cell value (the one it is if it isn't 0.1 or 0.05) is "NOT APPLICABLE FOR DISCOUNT". Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `discountplaceholder` as a `String`, but then you are assigning a value of type `Double` to it. Either declare `discountplaceholder` as a Double, or assign a `String` to it. `discountplaceholder = "0.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `Discounterplaceholder` as a `Double` or use `""` when you're assigning a double value to it to convert the `double` to a `literal`.

```
Dim discountplaceholder As Double
```

or

```
Sub CALULATE()
Dim postage As String
Dim discountplaceholder As String

discount = Range("d10").Value

If discount = "0.1" Then

MsgBox "hello Bill"
discountplaceholder = "0.1"

ElseIf discount = "0.05" Then

MsgBox "hello BOB"
discountplaceholder = "0.05"

Else
MsgBox "hello dan"
discountplaceholder = "0"

End If
End Sub
```